# ¿Como imprimir la matriz con los datos?

Tags: pseint

un Banco , quiere actualizar su programa de control de
presupuesto. Siempre se debe ingresar el monto del presupuesto y la reserva. Se permite
registrar un máximo de diez (10) gastos. Utilice una matriz par guardar la siguiente
información de cada gasto: descripción del gasto, monto del gasto, saldo disponible.
Nuevamente utilice un ciclo que permita el ingreso de los gastos pero que termine cuando el
usuario lo desee o cuando el saldo disponible llegue a cero.

Comment: Aqui no hacemos tareas...

Comment: Lo se, solo ocupo ayuda para mostrar la matriz con los datos, lo demás ya lo tengo hecho

Comment: Tienes que escribir al menos como lo intentaste.

Answer (score 0):

total mente de acuerdo, fue mi error lo siento.

aqui esta lo que hice pero a la hora de imprimir la matriz no me lo imprime, no se que estoy haciendo mal, gracias.

```
Algoritmo banco

        Definir presupuesto, reserva, monto, saldo, diferencia, gastos como real;

        definir gasto, matriz, info, s Como Caracter;
        definir i, j como entero;
        dimension matriz[10,3];
        Dimension gasto[10];
        dimension monto[10];
        Dimension saldo[10];
        info<-"";
        s<-"";
        i<-0;
        j<-0;
        Escribir "Ingrese el presupuesto ";
        leer presupuesto;
        escribir "Ingrese la reserva: ";
        leer reserva;
        Escribir "";
        diferencia<-presupuesto-reserva;
        Repetir

            escribir "Disponible  ",diferencia Sin Saltar;
            Escribir "";
            Escribir sin saltar "Gasto No.: ",(i+1) Sin Saltar;
            Escribir"";
            Escribir "Descripcion ";
            leer gasto[i];
            Escribir "Monto: ";
            leer monto[i];
            Escribir "";
            diferencia<-diferencia-monto[i];
            Escribir "¿Desea salir? S/N ";
            leer s;
            saldo[i]<-diferencia;
        hasta Que s="si" o i=10

        Escribir "No.      Descripcion       monto    Nuevo saldo" Sin Saltar;
        Escribir"";
        para i<-1 hasta 10 con paso 1 hacer
         escribir i+1, "            ", gasto[i],"         ", monto[i],"           ", saldo[i],"   ";
        FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y me dice que el fallo lo tienes en la condición de "Repetir hasta que".

Prueba a cambiar esa línea por esta otra `hasta Que s="si" | i=10` y luego ejecuta el programa, Saludos.